# Rebind same gridview again

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET page, Page1 and there is a gridview. There is also a linkbutton which takes user to Page2.  And, once user clicks a button on Page2, the page is redirecting to Page1.

I want to rebind the gridview on the Page1 with previous gridview again upon coming back from Page2.  So I am passing the gridview in the Session variables, and bind it to same gridview again, but it looks like it's not binding (No gridview displayed).

Is there any way I could preserve the gridview and rebind it upon coming back from another page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to put GridView in Session variable is not a good idea because it take lot memory ant time to convert it into string because every thing in Session variable is stored as a string.

So you can store DataTable or List (DataSource) in session and based on it you can call BindGrid function again like this.

### In Page1.Aspx

void Page_Load()
{
    If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["dataSource"]))
     {
         gridVies.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dataSource"];
         gridView.DataBind();
     }
    else
     {
         BindGrid();
     }
}
void HyperLinkClicked(sender s, EventArg e)
{
  session["dataSource"] = gridView.DataSource;
  Response.Redirect("`\Page2.aspx");
}

### In Page2.Aspx

Void Button_Clicked(Sender s,EventArg e)
{
  Response.Redirect("`\Page1.aspx");
}

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rebind it then call the binding logic from your Page_Load handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the GridView you have to persist its datasource f.e. a DataTable.